# Rails categories model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I can call `@product.categories`, but cannot call `@product.categories.name` or `@product.categories.parent_id`, why?

I use the Categorizable module in my Product model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
include Categorizable
end
```

I have the following models:

Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :categoricals
validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, presence: true
acts_as_tree order: "name"


def find_subcategories
    @subcategories = Category.where(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
end
end
```

Categorical model:

```
class Categorical < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :categorizable, polymorphic: true

    validates_presence_of :category, :categorizable
    end
```

Categorizable module:

```
module Categorizable 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :categoricals, as: :categorizable
    has_many :categories, through: :categoricals
  end

  def add_to_category(category)
    self.categoricals.create(category: category)
  end

  def remove_from_category(category)
    self.categoricals.find_by(category: category).maybe.destroy
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `@product.categories` returns a collection, not an instance.

`@product.categories.first.name` will work (assuming there are categories)

or loop over them

```
<% @product.categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```